# remove row from array if invoice reference is the same and the sum of amount is 0

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a large table of customers, invoice numbers, invoice reference and amount.
Sometimes invoices get cancelled/credited. When they are cancelled, they get unique invoice number, but same invoice reference as the original invoice.

I read the entire data into an array, but i am struggling with following:
In the case customer number and invoice reference is same and the total of the postings is 0, i want to delete these rows from my array.

Example:

| Customer | Invoice | Reference | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3233 | 91324941 | 91324941 | 143.966 |
| 3233 | 91323172 | 91323172 | 155.418 |
| 3233 | 91323173 | 91323172 | -418 |
| 3233 | 91330112 | 91324941 | -143.966 |

For this table i want only the invoice line 91323172 and 91323173 to remain.

| Customer | Invoice | Reference | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3233 | 91323172 | 91323172 | 155.418 |
| 3233 | 91323173 | 91323172 | -418 |

The two others needs to be removed, as they have the same reference and sum is zero.

PS! I have approx 70 customers and 4000 invoices to run this through...

Comment: This can be done ... but it isn't just a couple of lines of code. What have you tried so far? Suggest you have a go at solving your own problem and then come back and ask specific questions if/when you experience specific problems. As a hint, I would be copying the data to a new/temporary sheet, deleting the rows that are not required and only then read the data into an array, then delete the temporary sheet.

Comment: Strange hint. Magnitudes faster manipulating the arrays rather than pushing data around sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opton 1: Dictionary

- Group the full dataset by customer and reference columns, summing the amount column in the aggregation.
- During the groupby, track the original row index for each group in a dictionary.
- With the summed amounts, extract only the specific rows needed.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, arrData
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sKey, Cus_Ref As String
    Dim arrRes(), iIdx As Long, aRow
    Dim dAmt As Double, sCust As String
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    arrData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ' Dict key: Customer+Reference
    ' Dict item: Array(sum(Amount), row list)
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        Cus_Ref = arrData(i, 1) & "|" & arrData(i, 3)
        If objDic.exists(Cus_Ref) Then
            dAmt = objDic(Cus_Ref)(0) + Val(arrData(i, 4))
            sCust = objDic(Cus_Ref)(1) & " " & CStr(i)
        Else
            dAmt = Val(arrData(i, 4))
            sCust = CStr(i)
        End If
        objDic(Cus_Ref) = Array(dAmt, sCust)
    Next i
    iIdx = 1
    For Each sKey In objDic.keys
        If objDic(sKey)(0) <> 0 Then
            aRow = Split(objDic(sKey)(1))
            For i = 0 To UBound(aRow)
                ReDim Preserve arrRes(1 To 4, 1 To iIdx)
                For j = 1 To 4
                    arrRes(j, iIdx) = arrData(aRow(i), j)
                Next j
                iIdx = iIdx + 1
            Next i
        End If
    Next sKey
    ' Transpose(arrRes) is what you are looking for
    ' load result into worksheet
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(iIdx - 1, 4).Value = Application.Transpose(arrRes)
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Option 2: ADODB

Note: sheet name is `Sales`

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExtractADO()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSql As String
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" & _
        ";Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & _
        ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    strSql = " SELECT T1.* FROM [Sales$] T1 " & _
    " INNER JOIN (SELECT Customer,Reference FROM [Sales$] " & _
    " GROUP BY Customer,Reference HAVING sum(Amount)<>0) T2 " & _
    "  ON T1.Customer=T2.Customer AND T1.Reference=T2.Reference "
    rs.Open strSql, conn
    Sheets.Add
    Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Invoices"]}[Content],

//Set Column Data Types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Customer", Int64.Type}, {"Invoice", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Reference", Int64.Type}, {"Amount", Currency.Type}}),

/*Group by Reference and Customer
    Then Add the invoice amounts in that reference*/
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Customer","Reference"}, {
        {"Total Amt", each List.Sum([Amount]), type nullable number}, 

//Also retain the "subtable" for later expansion
        {"all", each _, type table 
            [Customer=nullable number, Invoice=nullable number, 
            Reference=nullable number, Amount=Currency.Type]}}),

//Select grouped rows where "Total Amt" is not zero
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each ([Total Amt] <> 0)),

//Remove the original Customer, Reference and the Total Amt columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Customer","Reference", "Total Amt"}),

//Expand the subtables
    #"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "all", {"Customer", "Invoice", "Reference", "Amount"})
in
    #"Expanded all"
```

[image]